# How can I denote in HTML a constructed language that has not been assigned an official language tag?

Tags: html

HTML has `lang` attribute I would like to use, but if I specify there anything different from ISO language codes (like `en-US` or `cnr-Latn-ME`), accessibility audits in Chrome start failing, SEO optimization tools raise warnings and an HTML document does not pass W3C HTML validator.

For example, this:

```html
<html lang="isv-Latn"> <!-- Interslavic in Latin script -->
```

Causes:

[image: Chrome SEO audit displays an error: <html> element does not have a valid value for its "lang" attribute]

For instance, there are [languages without ISO 639-3 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Languages_without_ISO_639-3_code_but_with_Glottolog_code), such as Interslavic (its unofficial code is ISV, but that is not a valid BCP47 code).

What am I missing here? How can I specify an exotic language of HTML document without triggering various validation errors?

Comment: To people who are voting to close this question, I sincerely ask you to explain why (even briefly is better than nothing). I strive to make a website accessible and friendly to robots, automatic translators, chrome extensions, etc. The website deals with a constructed (artificial language), and this is indeed a minor issue I would like to solve as best as possible.

Comment: Do you have a particular language you are thinking of? If I take one randomly in the wikipedia's list, [Limousin Dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limousin_dialect), and then I search it in [iana subtag registory](https://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry), I find I need to use `oc-lemosin`. (Note that `lang` uses [BCP47](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/bcp/bcp47.txt), not *just* ISO 639-3.)

Comment: @Kaiido, I am thinking of Interslavic (unofficial code is "isv"). Using it in markup results in warnings from audit tools and sometimes SEO too. I am clueless what to do best, to check somehow if user agent supports ISV and replace some placeholder language (for SEO and validation) like Slovenian after a check passes, or to just get rid of lang attributes at all. The former is also not really clear how to achieve. Sometimes I want to differentiate between isv-Latn and isv-Cyrl (two different alphabets). Lang attribute would come in handy, but apparently it creates more problems than it solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Kaiido for the idea. After googling what web developers do with *Toki Pona* language in their HTML, I found this information:

> ISO 639-2 and ISO 639-5 also have the code `art` for other artificial languages.[1] The BCP 47 subtag `x` can be used to create a suitable private use tag for any constructed language that has not been assigned an official language tag (e.g., `art-x-solresol` could be used for *Solresol*).

Hence, if I use `art-Latn-x-isv` or `art-Cyrs-x-isv`, it should be good enough, and I can continue using `lang` attribute.